# How to pass multiple values to 'SCHEMA_ID' in sys.objects table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am looking for a way to pass multiple values to the below query.

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.objects
WHERE schema_id = SCHEMA_ID('My_Schema');
```

Comment: ...just remove the `WHERE`?

Comment: @Lamak Sorry, I did not ask the right question before.

Comment: `WHERE schema_id = SCHEMA_ID('My_Schema_1') or schema_id = SCHEMA_ID('My_Schema_2');`

Comment: use an `IN`: `WHERE schema_id IN (SCHEMA_ID('Schema1'),SCHEMA_ID('Schema2'))`

Comment: I need to search for around 100+ objects. Is'nt there any easy way ?

Comment: then why are you filtering schemas?, how many schemas do you have?

Comment: Have around 300 schemas, need objects for around 100 schemas.

Comment: What kind of easy way to you envisage? You have to specify them somehow...

Comment: just as @DaleK said, one way or another you need to pass the values of the schemas you need. I guess you could have the schemas you want in a table and then join it with the `sys.objects` view

Comment: @DaleK I think this can be done by using a while loop and passing one schema id at a time, loading result set into a temp table.

Comment: @Lamak:  Yes, that is also a viable way.

Comment: Sure, but you still have to specify which schema's you are interested in somehow... solve that problem and you can probably find a set based approach.

Comment: if you are gonna pass the schema ids in a loop, that already assumes that you have those values somewhere...possibly a table....and then no need for a loop

Comment: You are best off joining to a table of schema names. How are you executing this? Directly in SSMS, from C#, Python, another client language?

Comment: I was able to get the required output by joining the sys.schema, sys.objects table to the schema names. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT so.*
FROM sys.objects as so 
inner join sys.schemas as ss on so.schema_id = ss.schema_id
WHERE ss.name in ('dbo','guest','sys');
```

Above may helpful to pull the data from sys.objects for multple schemas

Comment: [Bad Habits to Kick : Using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Comment: @Charlieface thanks i updated per your suggestion. However for the Adhoc query i believe suggestion can be ignored.. still thanks